# C# SmtpClient SendAsync from Static Helper Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I'm trying to write a helper class to send emails in my C# application. I would like to use `SmtpClient.SendAsync`, but apparently I'm not understanding how async stuff works or I have something set up wrong:

```
public class EmailService
{
    public static void SendMessage(MailMessage message)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25);
        client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // TODO: Log the SMTP error somewhere
            }
            var callbackClient = s as SmtpClient;
            var callbackMessage = e.UserState as MailMessage;
            callbackClient.Dispose();
            callbackMessage.Dispose();
        };
        client.SendAsync(message, message);
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an
>   attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported
>   within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method
>   should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

Based on this exception, it sounds like my `SendMessage` method probably needs to return a `Task`. However, `client.SendAsync` returns void so there doesn't appear to be any `Task` to return or `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generic async usage

To use `async` methods, your methods must be marked as `async` (all the way up the call stack). And when you have async method, you really want to avoid having a void return type. Most of the time you should return a `Task` (or a `Task<T>` if your method had an existing return type). You should also use [SendMailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses the new Task based asynchronous approach. And lastly, you need to `await` your call to async methods.

```
public class EmailService
{
    public static async Task SendMessage(MailMessage message)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25))
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(message, message);
        }
    }
}
```

### For Web Forms Only

Using async in Web Forms is a little trickier. You must mark the page as async.

```
<%@ Page Async="true" %>
```

One thing you'll notice with Web Forms is that you can't change the methods to return a Task for ASP.NET lifecycle events. So you need to register the task.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(SendMessage));
}
```

However, we need to be able to pass the message to the function. So we'll use a lambda.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => EmailService.SendMessage(message)));
}
```

Comment: I'm testing stuff out, but just a quick note... I'm using MVC, not WebForms. Just mentioned it because I see you improving your answer over time :)

Comment: @Sam Honestly, I'm figuring out how to do this over time because I haven't done much async in Web Forms yet. Since you're in MVC (which I have a bit of async experience with) you can just wrap your action method return values in a `Task<T>`, ex: `public Task<ActionResult> Index()`. Also, the convention is to end `async` methods with the suffix `-Async`, ex : `public static async Task SendMessageAsync(MailMessage message)`. That helps you have async methods alongside non-async and lets the consumer know they need to await the result.

Comment: So, in order for this to work I basically have to chain `async`/`Task`/`await` stuff all the way up my chain of methods? From the documentation, it looks like SendAsync should work: ***Sends the specified e-mail message to an SMTP server for delivery. This method does not block the calling thread and allows the caller to pass an object to the method that is invoked with the operation completes.***

Comment: Since you are being pretty thorough on your answer, be sure to dispose of your client.

Comment: @Sam [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't what you want to be using. That's to support an older form of asynchronous programming. The Task based approach is superior, and accessed via `SendMailAsync`. And yes, you need to chain it all the way up the call stack.

Comment: What is the proper way to clean up (dispose of client and message) after `SendMailAsync`?

Comment: @Sam Excellent question- I just looked into it and I don't see anything obvious. I don't think just wrapping it in a using statement is a good idea-what if the client is disposed of before the email sends? However, it's not like a database connection where you need to manually open it, so maybe you don't need to use a `using` statement even though it implements `IDisposable`.. I'm not sure. Probably have to ask someone smarter than me.

Comment: @Sam: Just dispose it after `await`ing `SendMailAsync()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SendMailAsync()`, which returns a `Task`.

Comment: I fleshed out your answer in my own, but if you take a look at the comments on mine, we're unsure how to properly dispose of the `SmtpClient` in an async context or even if it's necessary to do so. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: @mason: Just dispose it after `await`ing `SendMailAsync()`.

Comment: Isn't there a danger of the client being disposed of before the mail has been sent out though?

Comment: @mason: Not if you `await` the send.